# staging server for google-cloud endpoint app-engine connected android project

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin

I find a [very short article](http://www.streamhead.com/google-appengine-staging-server/) on how to create a staging server for app-engine. I am using Java. The essential idea is to create another application through the app-engine console. My particular problem is that I have been using the Google-Eclipse-Plugin (GEP) to design my app-engine connected android application. So **to me** there is restriction on changing which server my android app is pointing to. How do I overcome that hurdle? Please, be a bit detailed in responding (no non-actionable advise please).

Answer (score 1):

The linked article has some nice concepts but as you say it is a little short on details.  It looks like the main thing you need to know is how to tell Eclipse to deploy to a different Application Id.  If that is so, first browse to https://appengine.google.com/ and create a new application there.  Keep a note of its Id.

Make sure Eclipse is also logged in with your Google account.  Then right click on your project name, and select Properties right at the end of the context menu.  Expand the Google tab in the project properties dialog, then click on App Engine.  In the Deployment section you can change the Application Id to match your new Application.  I have tried to illustrate it with the example 'my-application-id-here' in the following screenshot.

[image: Eclipse AppEngine Properties]

Comment: Do I have to do anything to the front-end? My app is app-engine connected android application. How does the front-end know where to point?

Comment: I think I may have answered my own question: just regenerate the end-points.